# C# pinvoke of C function returning char*

Tags: c#, c, pinvoke, marshalling

This is what I came up with:

The unmanaged function:

```c++
extern  "C" __declspec(dllexport) char* callme(const char * sing) {
    char buf[10];
    sprintf(buf,"hey %s",sing);
    return buf;
}
```

The calling function:

```
class Program
{

    [DllImport("testnonclr.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Auto, CallingConvention =
        CallingConvention.Cdecl)]
    public static extern IntPtr callme([In,MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPStr)]
        string sing);

    static void Main(string[] args) {
        Console.Write( Marshal.PtrToStringAuto (callme("baby")  ));
        Console.ReadLine();  
    }
}
```

The result: a bunch of gibberish

Ok, thanks to the help of some users and more digging, this is what I ended up doing:

```
extern  "C" {
 __declspec(dllexport)  char* __stdcall callme(const char * sing)
{
static char *buf=NULL;
    char fubb[10];


sprintf(fubb,"hey %s",sing);
ULONG usize=strlen(fubb)+sizeof(char);
buf=(char *)::GlobalAlloc (GMEM_FIXED,usize);


strcpy(buf,fubb);

return buf;
```

}

}

and C#:

```
class Program
{

    [DllImport("testnonclr.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Unicode, CallingConvention =    C  
    CallingConvention.StdCall )]
   [return: MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPStr)]
    public static extern string callme([In, MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPStr)] string sing);
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        string rrr = callme("baby"); 
        Console.WriteLine(rrr); 


        Console.ReadLine();  
    }
```

}

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dangling_pointer

Comment: I would start with learning C first, and then try to P/Ivoke.

Comment: I know the ins and outs of C memory allocation as well as anyone, within the same file though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot return a pointer to a local variable since those are allocated on the stack (and the stack may get destroyed when the function returns).

You'd need to allocate memory on the heap (preferably using `CoTaskMemAlloc` so the CLR can free up the memory later) on your C function and return a pointer to that memory.

As a side note, you can directly return a `string` when marshalling (assuming it's a c null-terminated unicode string), no need to return `IntPtr`.

More info here: http://limbioliong.wordpress.com/2011/06/16/returning-strings-from-a-c-api/

Comment: I get Error:The global scope has no CoTaskMemAlloc

Comment: You need to include objbase.h

Comment: ok, I finally figured it out. thanks, used GlobalAlloc(GMEM_FIXED

Comment: GlobalAlloc is not the way to do it

Comment: someone here said they are the same thing: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/393509/usage-of-cotaskmemalloc