# std::string doesn't use custom allocator in first allocation

Tags: c++, stl, char, stdstring, allocator

I would like to create a custom allocator for `basic_string` that allows me to take ownership of the allocated internal array of the string. My specific use case is a .NET interop scenario, where marshaling back strings to managed code is expensive as it requires strings to be allocated in a specific pool (at least in [Windows](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5007216/213871)) and more important the ownership of the array in the heap must be transferred. I was able to code such custom allocator for [`std::vector`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59127415/213871) and verified compatibility in major compilers (MSVC, gcc, clang) successfully. I am now trying to use the same allocator for `basic_string` and I'm observing strange behavior, as all the major STL implementations seems to not use the provided allocator for the first allocation, tipically the first 16 bytes. It follows the code I am using:

```cpp
#include <memory>
#include <stdexcept>
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>

// The requirements for the allocator where taken from Howard Hinnant tutorial:
// https://howardhinnant.github.io/allocator_boilerplate.html

template <typename T>
struct MyAllocation
{
    size_t Size = 0;
    std::unique_ptr<T> Ptr;

    MyAllocation() { }

    MyAllocation(MyAllocation && other) noexcept
        : Ptr(std::move(other.Ptr)), Size(other.Size)
    {
        other.Size = 0;
    }
};

// This allocator keep ownership of the last allocate(n)
template <typename T>
class MyAllocator
{
public:
    using value_type = T;

private:
    // This is the actual allocator class that will be shared
    struct Allocator
    {
        [[nodiscard]] T* allocate(std::size_t n)
        {
            T *ret = new T[n];
            if (!(Current.Ptr == nullptr || CurrentDeallocated))
            {
                // Actually release the ownership of the Current unique pointer
                Current.Ptr.release();
            }

            Current.Ptr.reset(ret);
            Current.Size = n;
            CurrentDeallocated = false;
            return ret;
        }

        void deallocate(T* p, std::size_t n)
        {
            (void)n;
            if (Current.Ptr.get() == p)
            {
                CurrentDeallocated = true;
                return;
            }

            delete[] p;
        }

        MyAllocation<T> Current;
        bool CurrentDeallocated = false;
    };
public:
    MyAllocator()
        : m_allocator(std::make_shared<Allocator>())
    {
        std::cout << "MyAllocator()" << std::endl;
    }

    template<class U>
    MyAllocator(const MyAllocator<U> &rhs) noexcept
    {
        std::cout << "MyAllocator(const MyAllocator<U> &rhs)" << std::endl;
        // Just assume it's a allocator of the same type. This is needed in
        // MSVC STL library because of debug proxy allocators
        // https://github.com/microsoft/STL/blob/master/stl/inc/vector
        m_allocator = reinterpret_cast<const MyAllocator<T> &>(rhs).m_allocator;
    }

    MyAllocator(const MyAllocator &rhs) noexcept
        : m_allocator(rhs.m_allocator)
    {
        std::cout << "MyAllocator(const MyAllocator &rhs)" << std::endl;
    }

public:
    T* allocate(std::size_t n)
    {
        std::cout << "allocate(" << n << ")" << std::endl;
        return m_allocator->allocate(n);
    }

    void deallocate(T* p, std::size_t n)
    {
        std::cout << "deallocate(\"" << p << "\", " << n << ")" << std::endl;
        return m_allocator->deallocate(p, n);
    }

    MyAllocation<T> release()
    {
        if (!m_allocator->CurrentDeallocated)
            throw std::runtime_error("Can't release the ownership if the current pointer has not been deallocated by the container");

        return std::move(m_allocator->Current);
    }

public:
    // This is the instance of the allocator that will be shared
    std::shared_ptr<Allocator> m_allocator;
};

// We assume allocators of different types are never compatible
template <class T, class U>
bool operator==(const MyAllocator<T>&, const MyAllocator<U>&) { return false; }

// We assume allocators of different types are never compatible
template <class T, class U>
bool operator!=(const MyAllocator<T>&, const MyAllocator<U>&) { return true; }

int main()
{
    std::cout << "Test MyAllocator<char>" << std::endl;
    using MyString = std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, MyAllocator<char>>;
    MyAllocator<char> allocator;
    MyString str(allocator);
    str = "0123456789ABCDE"; // 16 bytes including null termination. No use of the allocator
    // str = "0123456789ABCDEF"; // 17 bytes including null termination. Here the allocator is used,
                                 // tipically doubling the space required
}
```

The output for the code follows, showing no use of the allocator. It's similar in MSVC, clang and gcc ([Wandbox](https://wandbox.org/permlink/8sQezincoNi0rySo) link):

```
Test MyAllocator<char>
MyAllocator()
MyAllocator(const MyAllocator &rhs)
```

Instead, if I have an allocation that requires more than 16 bytes, like the commented line in my code, the output is this in gcc (with similar output in MSVC, >= 24 bytes are required in clang):

```
Test MyAllocator<char>
MyAllocator()
MyAllocator(const MyAllocator &rhs)
allocate(31)
deallocate("0123456789ABCDEF", 31)
```

This shows a common pattern between all STL implementation, as it seems they just ignore the use of the allocator for small strings, as a sort of optimization. Sadly, library developers don't do it clean, as they could encapsulate any behavior in a custom allocator for strings exactly as I'm doing, probably wasting CPU cycles (and maybe storage) in branching. The question is as it follows: is the C++ standard not requiring to use the allocator in all data allocations? Is there a special clause/exception for strings? The same code seems to work just fine for [`std::vector`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59127415/213871).

Comment: Small String Optimization strikes again!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

What you are seeing is Short String Optimization (SSO).  The standard allows for `std::string` to be built with a small internal buffer that the string can use to avoid doing any dynamic memory allocation.  This is very advantageous since most strings are small so you can save a lot of allocations.

Unfortunately there is no restriction on the size of this buffer in the standard. MSVC uses 16 characters, libc++ uses 22.

This means that you'll either need to make sure you allocate a string that is big enough to use your allocator, or you'll just need to implement your own string class.  A trick to allocate enough memory is to use

```
std::string str;
str.reserve(sizeof(str) + 1);
```

since the buffer is part of the string if you ask for more memory then the size of the string it will have to dynamically allocate memory.

> Is there a special clause/exception for strings? The same code seems to work just fine for `std::vector`.

`std::vector` has a requirement<sup>1</sup> that moving a vector will not invalidate any pointers/references/iterators so that means it can't have such a buffer.  `std::string` does not have that requirement which allows SSO to be implemented.

<sup>1:</sup> [Table 71](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/container.requirements#tab:container.req) talks about `X u(rv)` and `X u = rv` and the complexity requirement is NoteB where NoteB is *constant complexity* for all containers except `std::array`, which has *linear complexity*.

Comment: "Cool", I guess. Is there C++ standard normative reference that I can safely use my allocator at least for `std::vector`? There's big possibility that I use that instead in my .NET marshalling scenario as strings are just array of chars and I just need append logic during a UTF-8 -> UTF-16 conversion.

Comment: @ceztko [Table 71](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/container.requirements#tab:container.req) has `X u(rv);` complexity Note B where *NoteB* is *constant complexity*.  This means there can't be a buffer since that would require copying/moving and that would be linear.  `std::string` has no such requirement.

Comment: It's a bit subtle, but theoretically 16/22 byte or whatever constant is still constant complexity, since it's not really dependent on user data.

Comment: @ceztko The complexity is about the operation itself.  Moving a SSO string will cost you O(N) character copies.  Moving a `std::vector` is always `O(1)` since no elements are copied or moved.

Comment: Good! If you can add last normative reference to answer, thank you. +1 right now.

Comment: @ceztko So Added.